# 'system program error detected' on startup, _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash file in \var\crash can't be opened or removed

Tags: xorg, crash, error-handling

I am running Ubuntu Studio 20.04.3 LTS with xfce, a fresh install since yesterday, and on every startup I get a "system program error detected" notification. There is one file in /var/crash named _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash but when i try to open or remove this file i get a 'permission denied' message, as such:

```
$ cat _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash 
cat: _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash: Permission denied
```

I don't find any problems with my system's functioning sofar, but I would like to know what these 'errors' mean and how to deal with them.

Comment: The file in `/var/crash` is a text file. Read it to get some information.

Comment: I am aware it's supposed to be a text file. When i try to open it with a text editor i get a pop-up:
 "Failed to open the document.
Failed to open file "/var/crash/_usr_lib_xorg.0.crash":open()
failed: permission denied."
When i try in the terminal:
$ cat _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash 
cat: _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash: Permission denied

Comment: Preface your `cat` (or `less`) command with `sudo `, type your login password when prompted.

Comment: That works! Thanks (feel stupid for not thinking of this myself).

Answer (score 1):

To read the crash file, you should use `sudo`, e.g. `sudo cat /var/crash/_usr_lib_xorg.0.crash`

If you would like to stop the notifications about a detected crash, you can simply delete the crash file: `sudo rm /var/crash/_usr_lib_xorg.0.crash`

This answer is taken from the [OP's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364739/system-program-error-detected-on-startup-usr-lib-xorg-xorg-0-crash-file-in#comment2342874_1364739)

Comment: I suggest killing off the crash system is not a good idea.